# override read only property to make it read write

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to create my custom `UIGestureRecognizer`subclass and I need to be able to set its state from within:

```
func fail () {
    self.state = .Failed
}
```

The problem is that when I am trying to override this read-only property, I get an error message:

```
override var state : UIGestureRecognizerState
```

> cannot override with a stored property 'state'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that when I am trying to override this read-only property

Do *not* try to override it. Instead, in the bridging header (which you might have to create for this purpose), import `<UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>`. Presto, the property becomes writable.

Comment: Example project here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch05p203gestureRecognizers/ch18p541gestureRecognizers

Comment: Thanks mate! Really helpful. I would just add that after setting up the bridging header with that import, there is no need for `override var state : UIGestureRecognizerState` anymore.

Comment: Good point. I'll add that to my answer, just in case anyone else stumbles on this the same way.

Comment: By the way, this mechanism is really idiotic and I've filed a bug report asking that it be abolished. The API should just admit that `state` is writable, rather than trying to hide that fact in a "secret" part of the API.

Comment: Would never have figured it out. Matt saves the day again.